# Manage importing nested dependencies using carthage

Tags: nested, dependencies, carthage

I have a framework called SampleFramework. This framework is used by SampleFrameworkTestApp. SampleFramework uses DependentFramework. I have added DependentFramework in the Cartfile of SampleFramework. SampleFramework is added as dependency in Cartfile of SampleFrameworkTestApp. If I run *carthage update* from SampleFrameworkTestApp it also downloads DependentFramework, which is expected. But is there a way to build SampleFramework without linking it to DependentFramework at all? I don't want to have two copies of DependentFramework. One in SampleFramework and one is SampleFrameworkTestApp. I want to avoid pushing DependentFramework as part of SampleFramework on git

Comment: There is no way to avoid linking the dependent framework. But the Carthage folder should not ideally be pushed to git repo. Also running carthage bootstrap/update command with --cache-builds command avoids the need to download frameworks again which haven't changed.